# Characters don't print right in WolframScript

Tags: scripting, printing, character-encoding

Mathematica version: 12.1 & 11.3

Platform: Windows 10

Since windows's `cmd` is GBK, so my file is GBK.

```
Print["1  ","所"]
Print["2  ","有"]
Print["3  ","所有"]
Print["4  ","法"]
Print["5  ","组"]
Print["6  ","组合"]
```

[image]

As we can see, some characters will affect other characters. So how to fix it? `CharacterEncoding -> "CP936"` seems useless.

Comment: I need more information. What are the values of `$CharacterEncoding`, `$SystemCharacterEncoding`, and `$Output`? Expand `$Output` to see what `Encoding` is. Check the [International Character Sets](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/InternationalCharacterSets.html) documentation. I suspect that if `"所" // FullForm` is  `\:6240`, then Mathematica is using UTF-8 character encoding.

Comment: Try `ToCharacterCode["有", "UTF8"]`.